# Are bots lured away by decoy grenades?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

My buddy and I are designing a co-op map in Counter-Strike Global Offensive.  We are curious if Bot AI is affected by Decoy Grenades, that is, do they move to investigate where the decoy grenade is making sounds from, or do bots ignore them altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bots will run to the site of a decoy.

> Bots will always run to the decoy so, if enemy's team has bots playing in it, you can easily kill them making them run to a decoy (unless they are controlled by players).

Source: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=394831667